# Header scroll issue

Tags: javascript, php, css

This is a wordpress site wherein i have an issue with header when i scroll down, you can see in the first image the header is transparent, then once i scroll down there is a glicth where the header is blinking while scrolling down with the background, actually the background should appear only when we scroll up,
please check the link, and try scrolling the page fast and you will see the blink in the header :[image]

Code : `

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var mywindow = $(window);
var mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
var up = false;
var newscroll;
mywindow.scroll(function () {
    newscroll = mywindow.scrollTop();
    if (newscroll > mypos && !up) {
        $('.header2').stop().slideToggle();
        up = !up;
        console.log(up);
    } else if(newscroll < mypos && up) {
        $('.header2').stop().slideToggle();
        up = !up;
    }
    mypos = newscroll;
});
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 300) {
        jQuery(".header2").addClass("dark");
    } else {
        jQuery(".header2").removeClass("dark");
    }
});
</script>
```

```css
.dark {
    background: #323232;
    position: fixed!important;
    border-bottom: none!important;
    margin: 0px; 
}
.site-logo {
    float: left!important;
    padding: 20px!important;
    margin-top: 0px!important;
    z-index: 999!important;
    position: relative!important;
    width: 200px!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="contain">
<div class="fixed-header">
  <div class="header2">
  <?php if(true === get_theme_mod('show_topbar')){ ?>
  <div class="fulltop">
  <div class="wrap"><div class="pm-left"><?php echo ( get_theme_mod( 'topbar_text' ) ); ?></div><div class="pm-right social"><?php my_social_media_icons(); ?></div></div>
  </div>
  <?php }?>
  <div class="wrap">
<?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'themeslug_logo' ) ) : ?>

.........
</div>
</div>
```

`

please help

Comment: Help us help you! How? Create a working example, please

Comment: http://brendanb.sg-host.com/                                                                                       Check this link...this is the live website

Comment: That is NOT how stackoverflow works, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)